# SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow errors when started

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, error

When starting a published SharePoint Designer 2013 List Workflow manually on a list item, I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.InvalidOperationException: No valid outbound signing keys were found. at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Any ideas on what may be causing this and how to go about fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens when the http activities were used in the workflows and mainly specific to workflow manager component in SharePoint 2013. more details as below:

## Workflow Manager Certificates

### Services SSL Certificate.

This is used for communication between Workflow Manager and its clients (for example SharePoint). When we register a Workflow Service with a SharePoint farm or otherwise interact with Workflow Manager, this is the bad boy that counts.

- This is a Server Communications Certificate.
- By default, its common name will be the FQDN of the first server in
  the farm (e.g. CN=FABWFM1.fabrikam.com).
- This certificate includes a Subject Alternative Name for the DNS
  domain (e.g. DNS Name=*.fabrikam.com).
- By default, this certificate is issued by the same FQDN. This is
  effectively a Self-signed Certificate.
- When additional servers are joined to the farm, this certificate is
  copied to the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities store.

### Encryption Certificate.

This is used for encryption of connection strings stored in the Workflow Manager Management Database.

- This is a Server Communications Certificate.
- By default, its common name will be the FQDN of the first server in
  the farm. This certificate includes a Subject Alternative Name.
- By default, this certificate is issued by the same FQDN.
- When additional servers are joined to the farm, this certificate is
  copied to the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities store.

### Outbound Signing Certificate.

This is used for securing communications between workflows and their clients and between different workflows (not between Workflow Manager and its clients as documented). This certificate is used to sign the security token portion of a HTTP activity, which includes the claims of the user that instantiates the workflow.

- This is a Certificate Signing Certificate.
- By default, its Common Name will be CN=WorkflowOutbound.
- By default this certificate is a CA Root Certificate so it’s issued
  by itself.
- This certificate is created when the first host is added to the
  Workflow Manager farm.

[Reference Link](http://www.harbar.net/articles/wfm1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by Microsoft Support by re-installing the workflow engine

Comment: pls give the proper explanation for the problem and possible references.